# What does "0 skipped, 0 blacklisted" mean in the Qt Unit Test framework?

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing

When I run my Qt Unit Test project, it ends with a summary that looks like this:

```
Totals: 28 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, 0 blacklisted
```

The "passed" and "failed" categories are obvious, but what is the meaning of "skipped" and "blacklisted"?

Under what conditions will the test framework skip a test? How is that different from blacklisting it?

My Qt version is Qt 5.4.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Test is skipped, if [QSKIP()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QSKIP) gets called from a test method/slot.

`QTestlib` looks for a file called `BLACKLIST` in the test directory and parses it if found. The file contains a simple ini style list of functions to blacklist. For details see [qtestblacklist.cpp](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/testlib/qtestblacklist.cpp).

For example, Qt5 has `BLACKLIST` file (without `.ini` extension) at `tests/auto/corelib/kernel/qobject` folder, with contents like:

```ini
[moveToThread]
windows
```

Which tells QTestlib to don't treat the `moveToThread` named `slot` as a test-case if the platform is `windows`, and instead, just increment "blacklisted" count.

Comment: why do we have blacklist pass and blacklist failed test case, if a test case is marked as blacklist then it should be ignored to run? https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-autotest.html#viewing-test-output