# How do you write a failing Qt Test that generates BFAILs and BPASSes?

Tags: qt, performance-testing, qttest

When searching through Qt files to for all the different Qt Test results, I came across `BPASS` and `BFAIL`. I'd like to write some passing/failing tests. The problem is, I can't find any examples of people writing tests that generate these results, and none of my tinkering has led to that either.

I'd have to install the source for more checking, but does anyone know how to get `BPASS`/`BFAIL` results from running Qt Tests?

I'm assuming it's for Benchmark-type tests, but I haven't written any benchmark tests that generate special `BPASS`/`BFAIL` messages, just your typical `PASS`/`FAIL!`/`XPASS`/`XFAIL`.

Comment: `BPASS` and `BFAIL` are the result of blacklisted tests.  See http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-autotest.html#viewing-test-output and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29397463/what-does-0-skipped-0-blacklisted-mean-in-the-qt-unit-test-framework.